# Remove SweetAlert button outline on focus

Tags: javascript, css, outline, sweetalert

I'm using [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) on my nodeJS project and it's working like a charm, except by the fact that when I show a confirmation modal it sets the focus to the confirmation button and it gets this awful outline.

This is how it is:
[image]

This is how I wanted it to be:
[image]

I already tried to override it's styles and set outline to none, but it didn't worked:

```
.sweet-alert button.confirm {
  outline: none !important; }
```

I've also tried to get rid of any outline with this style:

```
*:focus, *:active {
outline: 0 !important; }
```

This is the code I'm using to fire the SweetAlert modal:

```
swal({ title: "Confirmation", 
               text: "Are you sure you want to remove this credit card?", 
               showCancelButton: true,
               confirmButtonText: "Yes, remove it", 
               closeOnConfirm: true }, 
               doRemoveCard);
```

This is the piece of code within sweetalert.min.js that sets the focus:

```
a=o.querySelector("button.confirm");a.focus()
```

Any ideas on how can I get rid of this outline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .class:focus {
>       overflow: hidden; }

replace "class" with your required class

Comment: `.class:focus` isn't mentioned by the OP. Where should they find this class so they can change it?

Answer (score 11):

you can try this for sweetalert2 v7.x.x

```css
.swal2-popup .swal2-styled:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This question was originally posted 2 years ago, but for those looking for a solution in the latest version (2.1.x) use:

```
.swal-button:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an especific selector of pseudoclass :focus for get rid the outline (box-shadow) in the X Close button of SweetAlert, and apply these properties. Using only :focus is general, avoid it, try this especific css rule.

```css
.swal2-close:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

actually .**class** is optional you need to change with your button class like as **.sweet-alert button.confirm** find class with inspect element tool and set their focus overview hidden in your custom css.

Answer (score 0):

Using SweetAlert2 version 8.0.5 you might want to add a global :focus in your css files to prevent a blue outline

```
:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

That should help:

```
.sweet-alert button:focus {
     box-shadow: none;
}
```